# What are the benefits of choosing a higher difficulty in Resident Evil 6?

Tags: resident-evil-6

I started playing Leon's campaign in Professional as I always choose the difficulty before last...I would like for these questions to be answered please.

- What advantages do harder difficulties provide ??

  - More skill points ?
  - Achievements ?
  - Unlockables ?
- How much harder will it be to kill NPCs ?

Comment: There's a trophy/achievments for completing the game on Professional level, it unlocks the rest of the difficulty trophies as well. There are unlimited ammo-type skills that unlock once your finish the game on any difficulty as well as new game mode and new campaign. I believe there are new dog tags and/or titles as well.

Comment: Your comment should be an answer. Also, are these the only benefits ? Can you please confirm your sources of info ?

Comment: My info is mostly my own findings playing the game. While I'm certain about the trophies/achievements, the extra mode and campaigng and the unlimited-ammo skills, the rest is just a hunch, therefore I refrain from posting it as a complete answer

Answer (score 1):

There are achievements for completing the game in every mode except for No Hope. So completing game on Professional will unlock all of these achievements at once.

Number of received skill points is doubled for No Hope difficulty ([source](http://residentevil.wikia.com/wiki/Difficulty)).

All other unlockables are not related to difficulty setting.